# Building NMSSH for iOS

Tags: xcode6.1, ios8.1, nmssh

Platform: XCode 6.1 (iOS SDK 8.1).

I am using all default settings. I checked out NMSSH from xCode and tried to build the iOS project. It builds without any error, but there are no output files. I don't know where they are created either.

I am new to all these environment (mac, ios, xcode etc) and not sure how to proceed.

Comment: same problem here, suggestions?

Comment: I used cocoapods. It works

Comment: I fixed mine. For anyone else experiencing this issue: use a device as deployment target, not a simulator

Comment: Answer complete procedure

Answer (score 0):

When building the framework, just make sure that you have set an actual iOS device set as "active scheme" in the upper left corner, not a simulator. At least for me, that produce the required outcome -> the framework

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Cocoapods this will work.
2. If you have some other dependency in your project which is conflicting with Cocoapods:-

   a. Download the NMSSH master from github.

   b. Select target as NMSSH Framework

   c. Build the project

   d. Under Products you will have the NMSSH.framework

   e. Copy the NMSSH.framework to your project

   f. In your project Build settings drag the NMSSH.framework and add     libz.dylb and CFNetwork frameworks
   to your project.
3. If you find Linker issues while building your project 
   Follow steps in :- https://stackoverflow.com/a/39301886/1842304