# Alamofire Sudden Linker Failed On Simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, linker-errors, alamofire

All was fine and dandy until I merged a branch to master and executed the project from the master branch. Alamofire seemingly can't be linked when using the simulator for some reason (running on an iPhone 5 works perfectly).

To start off, I have tried the answers found here: [Xcode 6.1: file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055970/xcode-6-1-file-was-built-for-x86-64-which-is-not-the-architecture-being-linked) with no luck. Additionally, I tried the suggestions from this github page: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2053

Explicitly I have:

- Deleted Pod folder and Podfile.locl and then done pod install
- Changed 'Build Active Arch Only' (in project build settings) to Yes and No and for both debug and release.
- Set architectures to 'standard architectures'

Additionally, I have the following line in my Podfile:
`pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'`

Here is a screenshot of the errors I am getting:
[image]

Comment: try `Product -> Clean`. After that `Product -> Build`. Works most of the times.

Comment: Errors still persist after cleaning... any other suggestions?

Comment: Click on the linker error and post the screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete **Derived Data**

in Xcode 7.3

```
Window -> Projects
```