# iOS - file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I have an Objective-C project where I'm using the Charts framework (https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) in my app using Cocoapods, and whenever I try to test my app on an iPhone 4 simulator (whether regular or 4s), the build fails with the following errors in that it ignores the framework for the following reason:

> file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386)

I read here, [Xcode 6.1: file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055970/xcode-6-1-file-was-built-for-x86-64-which-is-not-the-architecture-being-linked), that I should:

> Make sure you have i386 and x86_64 listed in your Architectures in Build settings for your lib. Also set Build Active Architecture Only explicitly to No.

When I go to my `Pods` project settings, setting Build Active Architecture Only explicitly to No doesn't fix the problem.

Am I doing something wrong? I can provide screenshots if need be, because this is very confusing.

***EDIT***

This question is different from the inferred duplicate because the solution isn't working for me. I went into my project's "Target" settings and switched "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No", and it got rid of the original errors, but now I have 5 new issues:

[image]

Comment: I'm simply indicating that the solution provided in that answer did not work for me, as I have cited it in my question.

Comment: Hi Rafi Did you find a solution for this.? I am facing the same problem

Comment: did u solve the problem? I am facing the same problem now.

Comment: @ichanduu Please see my progress as indicated in my edited question

Comment: It seems it still is a dupe and your new problems should start as a new question.

Comment: @Eiko Thanks for the advice. So does that mean I should manually delete this question and ask another question about the new error? Or should I let this question be closed by a moderator?

Comment: @Rafi It's already closed as a duplicate - nothing to worry about. :-) If you can't find a solution for the new problems, just ask a new question, giving some context, and maybe link back to this question. Oh, do a search first - maybe it has been answered before. :-)

Comment: @Eiko It turned out that I didn't have to change my Project or Pods target Build Settings. Clearing my "Derived Data" worked for me. I have no idea how, but it worked and allowed me to test my app on an iPhone 4 simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you havnt this file (.m) in your Compile Sources? 
In Xcode go to Target > Build Phases > find Compile Sources section.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. I have a lot of .m and swift files in my Compile sources section in both my App target  and my pods targets

Comment: Ok, please show some screens. And I will try to describe what I mean exactly.

Comment: http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2016-07-22_at_4.10.54_PM-AspLck53.png

Comment: This shows the settings of my `Charts` framework target: http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2016-07-22_at_4.14.29_PM-aJvpgtFl.png