# twillo video sdk not working

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, xcode7.3

i am using twillo video sdk and its not working  after i pulled from the git repo.what is issue not able to get .

```
iOS/Pods/TwilioCommon/TwilioCommon.framework/TwilioCommon, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x76 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x20 0x68 0x74 0x74 0x70 0x73 0x3A 0x2F 0x2F ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/somendra/Documents/iOS/Pods/TwilioCommon/TwilioCommon.framework/TwilioCommon


iOS/Pods/TwilioConversationsClient/TwilioConversationsClient.framework/TwilioConversationsClient, file was built for unsupported file format ( 0x76 0x65 0x72 0x73 0x69 0x6F 0x6E 0x20 0x68 0x74 0x74 0x70 0x73 0x3A 0x2F 0x2F ) which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): /Users/somendra/Documents/iOS/Pods/TwilioConversationsClient/TwilioConversationsClient.framework/TwilioConversationsClient


Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWCCameraCapturer", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.TWCCameraCapturer in TwilioManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWCConversation", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.TWCConversation in TwilioManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWCIncomingInvite", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.TWCIncomingInvite in TwilioManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWCLocalMedia", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.TWCLocalMedia in TwilioManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TWCOutgoingInvite", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.TWCOutgoingInvite in TwilioManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TwilioAccessManager", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.TwilioAccessManager in TwilioManager.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TwilioConversationsClient", referenced from:
      type metadata accessor for __ObjC.TwilioConversationsClient in TwilioManager.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: try creating a issue on their github repo

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the pods were added to the repo using git lfs:

You need to have git lfs installed on the machine pulling the project too.

After you checkout your project from xcode go to the project folder in the terminal and run:

```
$ git lfs pull
```

to pull the 2 large files 
Pods/TwilioCommon/TwilioCommon.framework/Versions/A/TwilioCommon
and
Pods/TwilioConversationsClient/TwilioConversationsClient.framework/Versions/A/TwilioConversationsClient

Answer (score 0):

Are you following the install instructions for Cocoapods adding the following to your Podfile?

```
source 'https://github.com/twilio/cocoapod-specs'

target 'TARGET_NAME' do
    pod 'TwilioConversationsClient', '~>0.25.0'
end
```

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/sdks

There are manual install instructions there as well. Also, you might check you [architecture build settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055970/xcode-6-1-file-was-built-for-x86-64-which-is-not-the-architecture-being-linked) and let me know if you still encounter the issue after changing the settings there.